# Toggle Code Completion on and off shortcut in Jetbrains Webstorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How to Hide/Show Code Complation shortcut in Jetbrains Webstorm or to not show it's pop up temporarily on Jetbrains Webstorm or any other Jetbrains products. I mean I want to disable Code Completion temporary or toggle it on or off when I need it because it's taking a little screen real state. So I want to show it and hide it when I need to or just make it a little transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unselect 'Autopopup Code Completion' and call Completion explicitly (Ctrl + Space for OS X)

[image]